# Does Java heap memory change based on RAM?

Tags: java, memory-management

I know the default Java heap memory is 128 MB. Since it is the **default**, I want to know whether this memory get **automatically** changed according to the RAM size. For an example, for a machine with 128 MB RAM, heap memory 128 is too much and it should be automatically changed. Because if an application use all of 128 heap, PC will end up in a trouble.

please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Java 1.6 update 18 (and later), if unspecified, the default heap-size in a client JVM follows these rules:

> The default maximum heap size is half of the physical memory up to a
>   physical memory size of 192 megabytes and otherwise one fourth of the
>   physical memory up to a physical memory size of 1 gigabyte.
>
> For
>   example, if your machine has 128 megabytes of physical memory, then
>   the maximum heap size is 64 megabytes, and greater than or equal to 1
>   gigabyte of physical memory results in a maximum heap size of 256
>   megabytes.

Taken from the [1.6.0_18 update notes](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/6u18-142093.html)

In previous releases of Java heap size was NOT variable by default.

Comment: OK. Which means the default 128 thing has been changed. Awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: Am I the only one that think the rules are strange. Say your java application runs fine with default values on your 192 MB machine. Now, if you upgrade to 256 MB the same application could fail with OutOfMemory.

Comment: very good question...But I guess you wrongly asked it. Did you mean "Say your java application runs fine with default values on your 256MB machine. Now, if you downgrade to 192 MB the same application could fail with OutOfMemory"

Comment: @Hope No, his statement was as intended (and why it's odd - reducing memory and running out of memory is expected, increasing it and running out is very weird behavior). At 192MB, you get (192/2)MB, 96MB. At 256MB you get (256/4)MB, 64MB. You increase the amount of available memory, but you get less in Java.

Answer (score 3):

No, it won't be automatically changed unless you ask for it on startup using the `-Xmx` option.

You can't get more than 2 GB on a 32 bit machine in any case.  If you need more than that, you'll have to get a 64 bit operating system with lots of RAM.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there anyway to programmaticaly change the memory? Will that be be bad?

Comment: No, there's not.  Yes, it'd be bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify JVM heap size by using aptions -Xmx and -Xms

-Xmx - Max Size.
-Xms - Min Size.

You specify like

```
 -Xmx64m -Xms32m  (for 64 and 32 MB)
```

Answer (score 1):

No. It is not automatically changed. Look [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/11/hotspot-jvm-options-java-examples.html) for more on HotSpot JVM memory options  .

More [Here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/09/javalangoutofmemoryerror-permgen-space.html) on handling Java OutOfMemoryError.